# Who wrote the poem that begins "What have we not done for this country"?

Tags: poetry, quote-source

About 15 years ago I read a popular history (in the sense of popular science, not popular politics) of the 20th century which includes a short poem that I believe went as follows:

> What have we not done for this country?
>   Some of us gave speeches;
>   Others gave our lives.

This poem has stayed with me for years and I would like to know the name of its author. I can no longer remember the name of the book I read it in, and Google has been unhelpful in finding a source.

I remember the poem was translated from its original language and believe the poet was Hungarian, though I'm not 100% sure about that. It was definitely written in the 20th century and it is definitely from a country that was behind the iron curtain. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The great Turkish poet Orhan Veli Kanık wrote so neatly on the “great
> Turkish lies” more than half a century ago:
>
> “What have we not done for this country? Some of us have orated Some
> of us have died.”

Source: [Why ‘fair’ is just a four-letter word in Turkish](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/opinion/burak-bekdil/why-fair-is-just-a-four-letter-word-in-turkish-87497) (Hürriyet Daily News).

Comment: Great find, thanks! Have to admit I prefer the translation I remember more though... it's the repetition of "gave" that has always impacted me.